# Liferay Language switch issue

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I am trying to implement multiple language support in my liferay Project. For this i added below code in `portal_normal.vm`file of theme.

```
#set( $availLanguage = $stringUtil.split("hi_IN,en_US"))
<span id="language">$taglibLiferay.language("fm", null, "languageId", $toto, 0)</span>
```

which will add support for two language Hindi,English (United States).

and created hook for multiple language properties files.

```
<hook>
    <language-properties>content/Language_hi.properties</language-properties>
    <language-properties>content/Language_en.properties</language-properties>
</hook>
```

but whenever i switch my language its not changing.It always shows values from  `Language_en.properties` file

so to check whats happening i tried printing below values in theme

```
$theme_display.getLanguageId() 
$locale
```

but it always shows `en_US` even thought i changed language to `hi_IN`.

Looking for help to figure out whats going wrong.

Environment: `Liferay 6.1.1 CE GA2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add hi_IN language as `Available Languages` in Portal Settings if it is already not there.

To add this/or verify go to `Control Panel` --> `Portal Settings` -->  `Display Settings`

here you will find a input box `Available Languages` which shows all available locales (comma seperated), make sure you have entry for `hi_IN` in this input box.